# Spinner with jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, spinner

I'm trying to setup spinner load for my pages with jQuery Mobile. However spinner doesn't show itself when I'm loading something with Ajax. Here is my code. Any ideas what's wrong with it?

```
$("#invite").live('pageinit', function(e) {
  var render = function (items) {
    var view = '',
    index = 0;
    items.forEach(function(date){
      view +=
        '<div class="ui-block" style="background:white;">' +
        date.address
        '</div>';
      index++;
    });
    return view;
  };
  $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
  $.ajax({                  
    url: 'someurl.com/file.json',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#list').html(render(data.shared_dates));
      $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using jQuery Mobile 1.2 then you should be using the following:

```
$.mobile.loading( 'show' )
```

and

```
$.mobile.loading( 'hide' )
```

Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: I have tried this, but i guess my problem is where i call this code.

Comment: @sannySin It looks like you've got the show/hide code in the correct spots, here is a simple demo to show that it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/kksm2/

Comment: @sannySin, you can call the code within scripts tags in the HTML or within an external Javascript file. Just make sure you load the JQuery mobile file in the HTML, and any external Javascript files. Within HTML, you might have <script type="text/javascript">$.mobile.loading('show')</script>

Answer (score 2):

I am using this code to achieve that:

```
       $.ajax({url: server_url,
        data: save_data,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'successCallback',
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        },
        success: function (result) {
            // some code here
        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            // some code here
        }, 
       successCallback:function(){

        }
    });
```

This is an example for jsonp but logic is still the same.